i'm having bitsandbytes error while using unsloth in conda
I'm trying to finetune llama3 model from Unsloth uding the code presented in one of there Colab notebooks, but I'm having several issues while running the code on my system.
Following is the error I'm having. I'm using a conda Virtual Enviornment
I'm following the tutorial on github
(unsloth_env) llm@llm:/mnt/ssd/unsloth$ python3 run_unsloth.py
WARNING: BNB_CUDA_VERSION=121 environment variable detected; loading libbitsandbytes_cuda121_nocublaslt121.so.
This can be used to load a bitsandbytes version that is different from the PyTorch CUDA version.
If this was unintended set the BNB_CUDA_VERSION variable to an empty string: export BNB_CUDA_VERSION=
If you use the manual override make sure the right libcudart.so is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
For example by adding the following to your .bashrc: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path_to_cuda_dir/lib64

Could not find the bitsandbytes CUDA binary at PosixPath('/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cuda121_nocublaslt121.so')
The installed version of bitsandbytes was compiled without GPU support. 8-bit optimizers, 8-bit multiplication, and GPU quantization are unavailable.
/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/__init__.py:72: UserWarning: Unsloth: Running `ldconfig /usr/lib64-nvidia` to link CUDA.
  warnings.warn(
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/__init__.py:103: UserWarning: Unsloth: CUDA is not linked properly.
Try running `python -m bitsandbytes` then `python -m xformers.info`
We tried running `ldconfig /usr/lib64-nvidia` ourselves, but it didn't work.
You need to run in your terminal `sudo ldconfig /usr/lib64-nvidia` yourself, then import Unsloth.
Also try `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda-xx.x` - find the latest cuda version.
Unsloth will still run for now, but maybe it might crash - let's hope it works!
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/ssd/unsloth/run_unsloth.py", line 2, in <module>
    import unsloth
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from .models import *
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/models/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .loader import FastLanguageModel
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/models/loader.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .llama import FastLlamaModel, logger
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/models/llama.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ..kernels import *
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/kernels/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .cross_entropy_loss import fast_cross_entropy_loss
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/kernels/cross_entropy_loss.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .utils import calculate_settings, MAX_FUSED_SIZE
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth/kernels/utils.py", line 36, in <module>
    cdequantize_blockwise_fp32      = bnb.functional.lib.cdequantize_blockwise_fp32
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cextension.py", line 73, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._lib, item)
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /home/llm/miniconda3/envs/unsloth_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cpu.so: undefined symbol: cdequantize_blockwise_fp32


I tried matching the Cuda and torch versions but did not work

I am sure this will be of not help to most of people, though, the thing that worked for me was:
systemctl start nvidia-fabricmanager.service

